# How can I match this pattern with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, regex-lookarounds

I have over a hundred images with query strings I need to get rid of

for example

```
<img src="http://example.com/asset/test.gif?l=j6%2BNsqLlmq%2B7xLVmX4bLS50JYKpDzeoBjGl7Y6ti04qV%2BiEVQY0aFBoTKmamyAwv">
```

I'm using sublime text2 to find all the query strings and replaces them so they look like this

```
<img src="http://example.com/asset/test.gif">
```

I haven't been able to get my regex to match perfectly the closest I've got is..

```
/\?\l=(.*)\"/g
```

This matches the query string but it also picks up the last `"` how can fix this so that I only match whats after `?l=` because that’s consistent throughout all the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using positive look behind and  positive look ahead

```
/(?<=\?l=)(\S*)(?=\")/g
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dF9aD0/1)